# Loading Javascript variable with parsed javascript data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load my test data into a javascript object and then load the data into my heating timers. I have managed to get this all working by loading the code individually in to each timer, but I want to stream line my code and also improve my knowledge.

Below is my code to set up my pretend loaded data and how I parse it into a javascript object.

```
var heating_data_load = '{ "monh1": "07", "monm1": "30", "mont1": "19", "monh2": "09", "monm2": "00", "mont2": "11", "monh3": "12", "monm3": "00", "mont3": "21", "monh4": "14", "monm4": "15", "mont4": "11", "monh5": "18", "monm5": "45", "mont5": "23", "monh6": "22", "monm6": "55", "mont6": "11"}';

var heating_data = JSON.parse(heating_data_load);
```

The function below is where my problem lies.

```
        function load_deg_data() {
var switch_number = 6;
var days_of_week = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'];

for (var i = 0; i < days_of_week.length; i++) {
    for (var t = 1; t != switch_number + 1; t++) {

        var temphours = days_of_week[i] + "h" + t;
        var tempmins = days_of_week[i] + "m" +t;
        var tempdeg = days_of_week[i]+ "t" +t;

        var data_hour_load = heating_data.temphours;
        var data_min_load = heating_data.tempmins;
        var data_temp_load = heating_data.tempdeg;

        var hour_load = '#' + days_of_week[i] + '_timer #hour_timer_' + t;
        var min_load = '#' + days_of_week[i] + '_timer #min_timer_' + t;
        var temp_load = '#' + days_of_week[i] + '_timer #temp_range_' + t;

        $(hour_load).val(data_hour_load);
        $(min_load).val(data_min_load);
        $(temp_load).val(data_temp_load);

    }
}
refresh_heat_timers();
};
```

The problem line currently is:

```
var data_hour_load = heating_data.temphours;
```

the proper object is heating_data.monh1 through to monh6, I can see why it does not like my code, but with all my efforts I can not see how to load my data in a loop and set the variable temphours and use that as the second identifier for heating_data.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me to just understand how to use a variable at the end of my heating_data object.

I hope this is clear enough in my description of what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `temphours` is not the name of the property you want to access, but a variable holding the name, you can not use dot-notation to access the property. You can access a property with a variable name like so:

```
var data_hour_load = heating_data[temphours];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I required. After a few hours of banging my head against a wall, I can now see the light. I had tried heating_data.[temphours]; still keeping the period in betweenm but I was guessing many different compositions.Thanks again for your time and help.